# what is the physical significance of dielectric constant and loss tangent?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, solid-state-physics, dielectric, insulators

I want to know that the significance of dielectric constant and loss tangent behaviour. How it characterises the materials. and possible relation between the dielectric constant and polarisation ?

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE, Your question in werry brad and har to answer concecely. You you give some example where you are confued about how dielectric constant works.

Comment: Have you tried searching for these terms on the internet?

Answer (score 1):

The dielectric constant, $\epsilon$, is also called the relative permittivity of a material. If we take the word literally, it can be seen as how much the material "permits" an electric field to come in. This basically translates to how much a material will allow itself to be polarized. Consequently, a perfect electrical conductor (PEC) would have $ \epsilon = 0 $, since no field can form inside of its boundary. It's a **relative** permittivity, because it is measured relatively from the permittivity of free space ($\epsilon _0$). This is similar to how dB is a relative unit, implying a ratio. It wrongfully and historically called the dielectric "constant", but it is mostly variable. In general, $\epsilon$ depends on space (all dimensions), temperature and (perhaps most importantly) frequency of the oncoming wave.

Comment: Consider addressing the loss tangent as well - which describes currents flowing during AC polarization and show up as a phase shift and heating of the material.

Comment: @Floris thanks, the loss tangent is a little harder to find a physical meaning for though. In my understanding it is basically an angle measured in the imaginary plane, which is already fishy enough. But I think in the real plane it can be seen as a ratio of electric field energy that is eventually converted to heat or lattice vibrations.